# Can a unathorized user capture a ssl packet, resend it and login?

Tags: ssl

Here's the scenario:

We have users login on a secure connection.  Could an unathorized user capture packets sent from the users machine to the server and then resend them?  Would this allow them to login?

This is a homegrown login system running on coldfusion.

Comment: This sounds like an IT/Security question, not a programming one. You might find help at one of these sites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Because the attacker in this scenario will still need to negotiate his own SSL handshake with the server, he will be unable to replay the victim's packet verbatim.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I read this same thing in several other sources.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: not with a normal browser.

Long answer: yes, if the user is not careful, and discards the warning the browser provides for not matching server name/certificate.

[Good explanation](https://www.securetrust.com/resources/how-ssl-works) of how SSL works.